# Is it possible to close an account which was create using SystemProgram.createAccountWithSeed?

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I made an error creating an account with seeds. A program is the owner of this account. Is it possible for me to close this or only the program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the owning program may close an account.

Otherwise, you could use `createAccountWithSeed` for someone else, and still close their account.  For example, you'd create a token account with me as the owner, but then you can close it rather than me.  That would be catastrophic!

Comment: Yea makes sense. cheers Jon.